# convert html with inline svg to pdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I generate html code via foreach loop. And sometimes there can be inline svg code. This is partof my code which I think we need to find solution. I use TCPDF library. Please tell me how to fix this issue or maybe you can suggest another library easier to use than TCPDF. Thanks.

```
foreach($submissions as $key => $value){
        $field_value = htmlspecialchars_decode(preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$value['value']));

        if($fields[$fieldId]['type'] == 'signature'){
            $pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $field_value, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
            $pdf->Write(0, $txt='', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
        }   

        if($fields[$fieldId]['type'] != 'signature')
            $html = '<div><div class="value">'.$field_value.'</div></div>';
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    }
    $pdf->Output($submissions[0]['date'].".pdf", 'I');
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Which issue which solution? Whitout specfic description nobody can you serve an adequate response...

Comment: When output pdf the svg field is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suppose that you have an valid data for your signature...

so maybe first try to inject it directly.. and check whether it works or not

```
$svgtest = '<svg width="10cm" height="10cm">    
    <rect x="50" y="100" width="50" height="50"
          style="stroke: #000000; fill: none;"/>
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="50mm" height="50mm"
          style="stroke: #000000; fill: none;" />
</svg>';
$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svgtest, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responce. This is my svg data `$field_value = '<svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" width=\"12cm\"  height=\"4cm\"><polyline style=\"stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;width:100%;fill:#ffffff;\" points=\"116,54 \" ><\/polyline><polyline style=\"stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;width:100%;fill:#ffffff;\" points=\"145,36 \" ><\/polyline><polyline style=\"stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;width:100%;fill:#ffffff;\" points=\"183,69 200,81 232,100 258,111 272,117 276,118 277,118 278,118 282,118 292,115 304,111 \" ><\/polyline><polyline style=\"stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;width:100%;fill:#ffffff;\" points=\"344,88 341,87 329,87 304,87 264,87 223,87 198,88 180,93 169,96 168,96 \" ><\/polyline><polyline style=\"stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;width:100%;fill:#ffffff;\" points=\"10,57 11,56 24,54 43,54 69,54 102,54 170,66 212,74 242,78 261,80 271,80 273,80 285,74 299,65 313,56 318,53 \" ><\/polyline><polyline style=\"stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;width:100%;fill:#ffffff;\" points=\"321,50 315,51 303,58 293,66 287,73 282,80 272,85 263,87 253,89 245,92 233,97 224,100 214,104 206,106 196,108 187,110 178,110\" ><\/polyline><\/svg>';`